# ImportError: The HttpLocust class has been renamed to HttpUser in version 1.0

Tags: python-3.x, locust

I'm quite new to `Locust`, just started tinkering with it a couple of days ago.
To quick start, i was following someone else example as below,
file : `locustfile.py`

```
import random
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task
class UserBehavior(TaskSet):
    def on_start(self):
        """ on_start is called when a Locust start before 
            any task is scheduled
        """
        self.login()
    def login(self):
        self.client.post("/login",
                         {"username":"ellen_key",
                          "password":"education"})
    @task(2)
    def index(self):
        self.client.get("/")
    @task(1)
    def profile(self):
        self.client.get("/profile")
class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehavior
    min_wait = 5000
    max_wait = 9000
```

When i run locust from the current directory, i am getting the below exception,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/locust", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/locust/main.py", line 113, in main
    docstring, user_classes = load_locustfile(locustfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/locust/main.py", line 77, in load_locustfile
    imported = __import_locustfile__(locustfile, path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/locust/main.py", line 53, in __import_locustfile__
    return  source.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 399, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 823, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 682, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 684, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/koushic/kk-ldl/locust/locustfile.py", line 19, in <module>
    class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/locust/util/deprecation.py", line 23, in __new__
    raise ImportError(deprecation_message)
ImportError: The HttpLocust class has been renamed to HttpUser in version 1.0. For more info see: https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/changelog.html#changelog-1-0
```

Could someone help me to understand the issue here.

```
Python 3.6.9
pip 20.1.1
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just check the last line of the error message:

```
ImportError: The HttpLocust class has been renamed to HttpUser in version 1.0. For more info see: https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/changelog.html#changelog-1-0
```

If you're lucky all you'll need to do is change these two lines:

from locust import Http**User**, TaskSet, task

class WebsiteUser(Http**User**):

Comment: ImportError: The Locust class has been renamed to `User` in version 1.0. For more info see: https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/changelog.html#changelog-1-0 ( In my case there is a slight difference ,`HttpLocust` class has been renamed to `User` not `HttpUser`

Comment: The Locust changelog has more info about iit: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/changelog.html

Comment: Good job! pallllllllll